# How do you configure and inject JwtOptions in .net core 3.1 using TOptions?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, .net-core-3.1

In .NetCore 3.0 and 3.1 they removed the ability to inject services into the Startup class unless you intentionally build a second service provider and duplicate your singleton services (gross). Almost all examples of configuring Jwt Bearer tokens for authentication show something like this:

```
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

This is great when you are working in a static environment, but I'm working in an environment where these settings are dynamic and are pulled from a web service that issues out configuration settings.

I found a really good walkthrough for using **TOptions** here:

https://andrewlock.net/avoiding-startup-service-injection-in-asp-net-core-3/

I'm trying to get this options pattern to work with **JwtOptions**.

I have added this to my ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyServiceImplementation>();
services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer();
```

This is my new options class:

```
public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private IMyService myService;

    public ConfigureJwtBearerOptions(IMyService svc)
    {
        this.myService = svc;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        // Only configure the options if this is the correct instance
        if (name == JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        {
            //use your service to get your settings
            options.Authority = myService.GetAuthority();
            options.Audience = myService.GetAudience();
        }
    }

    // This won't be called, but is required for the IConfigureNamedOptions interface
    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options) => Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
}
```

Is there a concept I'm missing? Do I need to remove .AddJwtBearer() all together since I am now injecting options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple authentication schemes for IIS including Windows. The code above is working for me.